# Why promise runs before the timeout here?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, v8

In the code snippet below both the setTimeout and reject get executed asynchronous. My impression is that setTimeout pushes to the even queue, then reject pushes to the event queue. Then the setTimeout fetes and executes immediately, the the reject. All that means 6 to be logged first then 3, however o my shock the console logs:

```
3
6
```

why is that? Why reject before the setTimeout?

```
let promise = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(" 6 ");
        }, 0);
        reject(" 3 ");
        resolve(" 4 ");
    }
);
promise.then(
    function (st) {
        console.log(st);
    },
    function (st) {
        console.log(st)
    }
);
```

Comment: `setTimeout` will always execute "later" than the current code. So, the operation here is delay a function (logging `6`) -> reject with `3` -> resolve with `4` (but the promise is already rejected) -> /* later */ -> log `6`

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&ab_channel=JSConf it is explained how js works

Comment: job que has a higher priority then task que

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the event loop as defined in the [Web Spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#event-loop-processing-model). The browser has multiple task queues for multiple types of tasks (e.g. timer tasks created through setTimeout), as well as a microtask queue (where Promise settlement gets pushed to). Whenever the browser finishes executing a task, it empties the microtask queue and executes all tasks in it, before continuing with a task from another task queue.

Timeout and Promises both execute code in async way but they have different purpose and charecterstics:

`setTimeout` delays the execution of a function by specific time duration and does not block the rest of code. Basically `setTimeout` schedules a macrotask.
`Promise` too does not block rest of the code unless you are using await operator but creates a microtask.

Since microtasks are executed before running the next macrotask, `Promise` will always be `resolved/rejected` before `setTimeout`.

Now in order to get the desired output you need to move the `reject()` call inside `setTimeout`

```
let promise = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(" 6 ");
            reject(" 3 ");
            resolve(" 4 ");
        }, 0);
    }
);
```